# how to view java system properties in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

I know how to set them through the use of

```
-Dpropertyname=property
```

Can I view this in the debug view within eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the Expression view and create a new expression with the following text:

```
System.getProperty("propertyname")
```

To show the Expression view: Click on Window Menu -> Show View -> Others... -> Type Expr -> Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no direct way of doing this, that I know of, you can always print it out with

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("yourProperty"));
```

You can then view the property in the console. Although this is not a very good way it seems to be the only one.